# My discord.py is not joining voice channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

can someone help me, well I put it like this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

[reference](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+discord+bot+join+voice+channel)

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/803764140933906433/840781103971172413/aASas.PNG what do i do when it says this?

Comment: tip: don't use images past your text here.

Comment: "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice"

Comment: This has nothing related to your code you have posted. This has something to do with `voice`. I suggest posting another question.

Comment: oh no nvm i figued it out

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped out.https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers